# Non frozen collections and user defined types on Cassandra 2.1.8

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I'm trying to run the following example from [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql-in-2-1)

```
  CREATE TYPE address (
          street text,
          city text,
          zip int
      );

 CREATE TABLE user_profiles (
      login text PRIMARY KEY,
      first_name text,
      last_name text,
      email text,
      addresses map<text, address>
  );
```

However, when I try to create the `user_profiles` table, I get the following error:

```
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Non-frozen collections are not
allowed inside collections: map<text, address>
```

Any thoughts on why this could be happening?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am running 2.1.8 and I get the same error message.  To fix this, you need the `frozen` keyword:

```
 CREATE TABLE user_profiles (
      login text PRIMARY KEY,
      first_name text,
      last_name text,
      email text,
      addresses map<text, frozen <address>>
  );
```

[Frozen](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/collection_type_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_exb_vg5_yj__using-frozen-in-collection) is necessary for UDTs (for now) as it serializes them into a single value.  A similar, better example for you to follow might be the one in the [User Defined Type documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/cqlUseUDT.html).  Give that a try.

Answer (score 11):

I was getting this message when I mistakenly used "string" instead of "text" in a cassandra map, like:

```
mymap map<bigint, string>
```

I followed this stackoverflow thread from google and I thought this information could save someone a few minutes of their time.

Comment: It just did. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Non-frozen UDTs are not yet supported. The reason for asking the user to explicitly specify this keyword for each UDT is to be able to introduce [mutable UDTs](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7423) in 3.x without breaking existing code.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, Stefan!  I thought it was specific to collections; so I've fixed my answer as well.