# Cassandra Springboot Frozen column exception

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra

I have a springboot application which I hooked up with cassandra. I am trying to create a map inside a map but getting the below exception.

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Non-frozen collections are not allowed inside collections: map<text, map<text, int>>
```

Code

```
@Table
@Data
public class AssessmentSubmissionEntity {

    @PrimaryKey()
    private UUID id;

    @Column
    private Map<String, Map<String,Integer>> assessmentMap;


}
```

man

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're have frozen collections in the database, you also need to mark whole column as `@Frozen`, or for maps you can mark the key or value as frozen with `@FrozenKey` and `@FrozenValue` if you want to freeze only particular part of the map. Here is example to froze the whole column.

```
@Table
@Data
public class AssessmentSubmissionEntity {

    @PrimaryKey()
    private UUID id;

    @Frozen
    @Column
    private Map<String, Map<String,Integer>> assessmentMap;    
}
```

If you want to freeze only the data inside Map, then you need to write it as:

```
    @FrozenValue
    @Column
    private Map<String, Map<String,Integer>> assessmentMap;
```

More information & examples is in the [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/object_mapper/creating/#mapping-collections).

Comment: I'm still getting this exception. Some how JPA doesn't seem to be recognising the frozen value. It still send cal query without frozen. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: You mentioned only Spring Boot so I did think that you use Object Mapper from DataStax driver & gave you a link to its documentation. If you're using Spring Data for Cassandra, then you can't make it work until the https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-465 is implemented...

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look into [Non frozen collections and user defined types on Cassandra 2.1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953841/non-frozen-collections-and-user-defined-types-on-cassandra-2-1-8).

You need to add frozen keyword:

```
@Column
private Map<String, frozen Map<String,Integer>> assessmentMap;
```

Comment: I knew this but how do i do it with spring